# BDD test like cucumber or JBehave on Scala

Tags: scala

I´ve been looking for a BDD framework for Scala, I´ve found this one https://github.com/maiflai/gradle-scalatest but to be honest I dont know how to run the tests and also how apply pure BDD test into.

Anybody here that has used this one or maybe another one, could share his github BDD test and gradle build conf to see how it looks like?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided is a method of getting scalatest working inside a gradle environment. Since Scala probably works better in the sbt environment, you may want to rethink that.

The real engine you are looking for is scalatest. Here is a short write up about [scalatest using BDD terminology](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tests_as_specifications). The documentation on scalatest provides plenty of examples of running it, using a number of different paradigms.

Comment: I already create some scenarios using the scalaTest, but does not make me feel as BDD test but Unit test.

Comment: Did you use the trait `GivenWhenThen` to provide a more BDD-specific narrative? You might also want to look at `FeatureSpec` if you are uncomfortable with unit testing. However, I'm not sure why you think BDD isn't about unit testing.

Comment: Yep, but the problem with that aproach is that the steps cannot being reused as feature or story steps on cucumber and jbehave.